# echo into a file while maintaining escaped spaces?

Tags: bash

Without updating `update_history` how can I ensure my text file will contain:

```
hello\ world john\ doe
```

That is how can I pass `$greeting $name` to a function or command as `hello\ world john\ doe`.

---

```
function update_history {
  history=/tmp/hist
  grep -qF "$1" "$history" \
    || (combinations=$(echo "$1" | cat - $history) \
        && echo "$combinations" > $history)
}

greeting=hello\ world
name=john\ doe

update_history "$greeting $name"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose the parameter expansions in double quotes:

```
update_history "$greeting" "$name"
```